# vb.net - hide column in datagridview based on its name

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

Is it possible to hide a column based on the column name?

I know that if I know the column ID, I can use that like so...

```
 TechSearch.Columns(0).Visible = False
```

I Want to do something like this...

```
 TechSearch.Columns("Details").Visible = False
```

I've tried that, and the 'Details' column is still visible.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have the Column Name and not its Header Text?

Comment: The datagridview is bound to a datatable which is populated from Mysql... the column name in mysql is definately "details". I did drop the uppercase D also and tried that, but still no luck.

Comment: What about checking the name via `TechSearch.Columns(0).Name`, or even trying: `TechSearch.Columns(TechSearch.Columns(0).Name).Visible = False` as a test for your theory?

Comment: Verify the actual name at run-rime. Set a breakpoint where you're trying to hide the column and inspect the columns assigned names (not the header text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is actually correct...

```
 TechSearch.Columns("Details").Visible = False
```

There was an exception just before this which was causing it not to hide this column.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

This is perfect

```
TechSearch.Columns("Details").Visible = False
```

Please just make sure that the datasource is loaded first before hiding the column.

It's good practice to edit/customize your grid on the `DataSourceChanged`.
From what I imagined is that you are editing the grid before loading the datasource :).